# For how long before standardisation was `string` available?

Tags: c++, history

C++ was formally standardised in 1998, but how far back can we find a class named `string` that looks like `std::string` does in C++2003 in a pre-standard C++ implementation?

I ask because `CString`, as part of MFC, has been "out there" since 1992 and I'm trying to determine whether it was first seen before or after what eventually became `std::string`.

Comment: Oldest one I still have has a 1994 copyright from Rogue Wave.  STL was first presented in Nov 1993.  Hard to see how that changes anything you'd work on today.

Comment: How on earth is this off-topic?!

Comment: @HansPassant: It doesn't. The practical problem here is that I wish to know.

Comment: I'm sure that the version Rogue Wave had in 1994 wasn't the same as what was formalized in C++98.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well before. In 1992 everybody was still rolling their own string classes. Remember that `std::string` was originally terrible, and then it became terrible *and* an STL-style container- but that was very late in the process, as the Committee delayed the first Standard for two years to fit in the STL and everything Stepanov needed. So `std::string` wasn't finalized until fairly late.

Comment: I still like rolling a custom String class from time to time; while std::string is "well-tested" and "powerful", there's some nice things that can be done with custom String classes, like built-in hashing, memory optimization on specific architectures, simplification of interface design, and so on.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja: I sometimes reinvent new wheels for my bike. They don't often roll that well, but they give a nice kick with the bumps.

Answer (score 2):

You might find one somewhat similar before 1998, but in
practice, it was several years *after* the standard before you
could more or less count on one being there.  And the earlier
ones were at best "sort of" similar; I remember noting the
absense of `push_back` in one of the committee drafts (the last
one, I think), which was an obvious oversight, that wouldn't
have occured if anyone had implemented a version with the
function.